# Java Checkstyle Rule To Restrict Method Empty Lines

Tags: checkstyle

Is there a way to setup checkstyle to prevent leading, multiple or trailing empty lines in method bodies:

e.g.

```
private void a() {
-
int a = 1;
doStuff(a);
-
-
doMoreStuff(a);
-
}
```

In the example above, I have denoted empty lines with `-` characters.

I'd like to be able to to prevent the leading line, trailing line and more than one line in the method body.

Comment: Use an automatic code formatter.

Comment: The aim is to enforce this via checkstyle rules so that an automated build can validate the formatting and perhaps fail a CI build if someone were to forget to apply the formatter.

Answer (score 3):

To prevent leading empty lines in method bodies, you can use:

```
<module name="RegexpMultiline">
    <property name="message" value="Blank line at start of method should be removed"/>
    <property name="format" value="\(.*\)\s*\{\s*\n\s*\n"/>
</module>
```

We can find method by parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

To enforce no blank lines at the beginning and end of any block, you can use **multi-line regular expression** checks:

```
<module name="RegexpMultiline">
    <property name="message" value="Blank line at start of block should be removed" />
    <property name="format" value="(?&lt;=\{\s{0,99}$)^$" />
    <property name="fileExtensions" value="groovy,java" />
</module>
<module name="RegexpMultiline">
    <property name="message" value="Blank line at end of block should be removed" />
    <property name="format" value="(?&lt;!\{\s{0,99}$)^$(?=^\s{0,99}\})" />
    <property name="fileExtensions" value="groovy,java" />
</module>
```

**"^$"** signifies the blank line.

Comment: Looks promising but seems to match all newlines, even before or after methods or field declarations.

Comment: Here is a more robust expression for the start of a block:

                            <module name="RegexpMultiline">
                                <property name="message" value="A blank line at the start of a block should be removed."/>
                                <property name="format" value="\{\s*[\r]?\n\s*[\r]?\n"/>
                                <property name="fileExtensions" value="java"/>
                            </module>

Comment: Here is a more robust expression for the end of a block: <module name="RegexpMultiline">
                                <property name="message" value="A blank line at the end of a block should be removed."/>
                                <property name="format" value="[\r]?\n\s*[\r]?\n\s*\}"/>
                                <property name="fileExtensions" value="java"/>
                            </module>

Answer (score 0):

To prevent multiple empty lines you can use the [`EmptyLineSeparator`](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_whitespace.html#EmptyLineSeparator) check. Its primary purpose is to ensure that there is an empty line between members in a file, but it also has a `allowMultipleEmptyLines` property which you can set to "false" to disallow them.

There is however currently a [bug](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/2974) with the check that means it doesn't correctly detect multiple empty lines between methods where there is a comment (including JavaDoc) between the methods. I am working on a [fix](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/pull/5486) for this at the moment.

As for checking for new lines at the beginning or end of a block, I think the `RegexpMultiline` check would be the only option as mentioned in Pankaj's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can use it:

```
<module name="Regexp">
    <property name="message" value="Blank line at start of block is not allowed"/>
    <property name="format" value="\{\s*$^\s*$"/>
    <property name="ignoreComments" value="true"/>
    <property name="illegalPattern" value="true"/>
</module>
<module name="Regexp">
    <property name="message" value="Blank line at end of block is not allowed"/>
    <property name="format" value="^\s*$^\s*\}"/>
    <property name="ignoreComments" value="true"/>
    <property name="illegalPattern" value="true"/>
</module>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggestion for checking for blank lines at the beginning of method

```
<module name="RegexpMultiline">
    <property name="id" value="RegexpMultilineEmptyRowBeforeStartOfMethod"/>
    <property name="message" value="Blank line at start of method or block should be removed"/>
    <property name="format" value="\)(\s)*\{\r?\n(\s)*\n"/>
    <property name="fileExtensions" value="java"/>
</module>
```

Answer (score 0):

[check-tfij-style](https://github.com/tfij/check-tfij-style) contains a checkstyle check to restrict **any** empty lines in methods or constructors. Just add maven/gradle dependency to checkstyle plugin:

```
plugins {
    java
    checkstyle
}

dependencies {
    checkstyle("pl.tfij:check-tfij-style:1.5.1")
}
```

Then add the check to your checkstyle config:

```
<module name="MethodEmptyLines"/>
```